# How to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] In Session Header 'Location:' to give path

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to use this code to handle sessions and if the user is not logged in he/she should be redirected to the home.

However the path I need to give inside the header(location) should be an absolute pat since Im using this session throughout the pages in different folders.

For this I'm trying to use the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`  root directory global variable. But my code is not working.

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with this code

```
<?php 

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['ID'])){
    header("Location:" . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/page1/page2/index.html");
 }

?>
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is the file system path to the document root, not the URL. The URL to the document root is `/`, unless you have your code in a sub folder, so use `Location: /page1/page2/....`

Comment: You'll need to define *"Not working"*. Any errors? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is an absolute path on your server's file system, **not** the relative path accessible from the browser.

In this case, the following will accomplish what you want:

```
header("Location: /page1/page2/index.html");
```